# Linker error with SFML

Tags: c++, linker-errors, sfml

I get a series of errors when running `g++ -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system main.cpp` on the example SFML code, when running Ubuntu, SFML 2.2 and g++ 4.8.2. I've tried reinstalling SFML from the package manager (`libsfml-dev`) and nothing works.

Example SFML Code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
/tmp/ccVG6GjG.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `sf::String::String(char const*, std::locale const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings cons'
main.cpp:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `sf::Color::Green'
main.cpp:(.text+0x196): undefined reference to `sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b6): undefined reference to `sf::Window::close()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1cf): undefined reference to `sf::Window::pollEvent(sf::Event&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to `sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x22b): undefined reference to `sf::RenderStates::Default'
main.cpp:(.text+0x236): undefined reference to `sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x245): undefined reference to `sf::Window::display()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x254): undefined reference to `sf::Window::isOpen() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2a9): undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()'
/tmp/ccVG6GjG.o: In function `sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2sf11CircleShapeD2Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2sf11CircleShapeD2Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for sf::CircleShape'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2sf11CircleShapeD2Ev[_ZN2sf11CircleShapeD5Ev]+0x2b): undefined reference to `sf::Shape::~Shape()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You mentions errors but you should actually write them -- readers don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Hiura when I made the question I originally had the error code but SO complained that I had too much code and 'not enough details'

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are referring to, but my guess is that they asked for a SSCCE. That doesn't mean you should not mention the actual error you have. If someone is having the same error as you did, using Google or any other search engine will not yield this question and as such it's pretty useless.

Comment: @Hiura The problem was that because it is in a Q/A format I didn't write very many details, and SO saw I had two big blocks of code (the SFML example and the error), so complained I didn't have enough detail. I'll try to add the error now that I'm back on my Linux PC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue. The first is to swap some of the options so the command goes like this: `g++ main.cpp -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system`. The second option is to try updating g++ to version 4.9.2, which can be achieved on ubuntu [by doing this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428198/getting-installing-gcc-g-4-9-on-ubuntu)

Comment: I have g++5.4.0 but I still get the error even after swapping the options,

Comment: I have g++ 6.3.1 and still get the error. Swapping the options like you suggested did not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

clang++-3.6 (package **clang-3.6** LLVM based) works for me and is part of package repo. g++-4.8.2 didn't work with reordering libs either.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the compile command for GCC which would be `g++ -c`.
This would give you a default object file which you can then run from terminal.
If it helps, my standard scripts that always work would be program => files => includes/libraries => object => Linker files

So an example in this case would be
Console: `g++ -c main.cpp -o sfmlApp -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system`
Console: `./sfmlApp`

Where `-c` is compilation and `-o` names the default object file.

If you are using libsfml-dev on most Linux distros you may have to append the include and library files with the compilation and object instance. The tutorial shows it as adding: 
Console: `g++ -c main.cpp -o sfmlApp -L /sfml-install-path/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

Where `-L /sfml-install-path/lib` would be the literal download location of the Linux version from the website. This should work for Ubuntu if I recall but you may have to add one more step as seen in the website tutorial for the overhead to get it started.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/sfml-install-path/lib && ./sfml-app
g++ -c main.cpp -o sfmlApp -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-system
```

That should at least get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The  solution is simple . You are not passing arguments in correct order .

Right order

```
g++  -lsfml-graphics  -lsfml-system -lsfml-system main.cpp
```

You need to always pass arguments in correct order.

```
Graphics
Window
Audio
Network
System
```